# How the cart price rule is applied in custom module?

Tags: magento2, sales

I followed mageworx blog to add Conditions fieldset in my custom module and I added it successfully.

https://blog.mageworx.com/2016/09/magento-2-module-with-conditions-model-fieldset/

Now, how can I apply it to order complete observer?

Would anyone please help me?

Comment: Hi. What exactly you want to apply and in which place yo make validation? Could you share your module on GitHub or somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to add this validation in my observer after the order is placed, if the rule condition matches with the current quote my custom entry is added in the custom table, otherwise, it won't be added. Please note that this is my custom rule like mentioned above Mageworx link. for order placed observer I have added it on "sales_order_save_after" event. I hope I explained enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer to apply validation to my custom rule. Below is working code if it helps to anyone.

```
  $rule->afterLoad();
  if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
    $address = $quote->getBillingAddress();
  } else {
    $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
  }
  if($rule->validate($address)){
    return $rule;
  }
```